# Questions regarding references and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Consider this simple class:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test() { data = 0; };
    Test(int integer);
    int getData() { return data; }
    ~Test();
private:
    int data;
};
```

If I write:

```
Test t = *new Test;
```

Would a new `Test` object be created on the heap and then copied to the temporary `Test` object `t`? And there would be a memory leak?

Also why is this invalid?

```
Test* t = new Test(0);
int i = *t.getData();
```

But this is not:

```
Test* t1 = new Test(0);
Test& t2 = *t1;
int i = t2.getData();
```

I know I can simply do `t->getData()` but I do not understand why the example above does not work?

Comment: You can use something like (*t).getData() because *t.getData will try to apply `operator*` on the return of the function `getData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would a new Test object be created on the heap and then copied to the temporary Test object t? And there would be a memory leak?

Yes and yes.

---

> Also why can't I do this:

The [member of object access operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) (`.`) has priority over `*`. You can do `(*t).getData()`.

Comment: You're a member access operator.

Comment: You're `vector<bool>`

Answer (score 0):

> Also why can't I do this:
>
> ```
> Test* t = new Test(0);
> int i = *t.getData();
> ```

You can't do that because `.` has higher priority than `*`. You can either use `()` to explicitly order the operations or use `->` which is a builtin shorthand operator:

```
int i = t->getData();
```